# Native Heap Exploding on Kindle Fire

Tags: javascript, android, dalvik, heap-memory, kindle-fire

Im writing an application that ideally will support all android devices about SDK 15, which includes the new Amazon Fire OS on devices like the Kindle Fire. I use webview fragments and load html/javascript into these fragments inside a view pager. Running on any google device, this works fine. But When I run it on a Kindle Fire, The ('Unknown' section of) native memory Heap becomes huge and eventually crashes the app.

I am wondering what kinds of allocations go towards the Unknown native heap, and if there is any difference between the webkit running on google phones and the webkit running on amazon devices that would cause this.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Fire OS, maybe it likes linux system. I suggest you use `showmap` to analysis the memory usage in Fire OS. `showmap` == `/proc/pid/smap`